# Simple TCP/IP client not working as expected

Tags: c++, sockets, client, tcp

I am attempting to write a very basic TCP/IP client that will simply request user input, send that input to the specified IP, then read the output. The code below does not return any of the error codes but the output is still not returning as expected. For example, the device I am testing this on should respond like so:

> some output here
>   
>  >

Where the last ">" is returned by the device to the client to signify it is ready for more input. However, with my code all that is returned is the ">". Weirder yet, it only returns that char on every other command, with those in between returning nothing. I suspect this has to do with how I am handling the buffer; perhaps a conflict in reading the CR and/or LF chars? The device in question works perfectly over telnet (same machine, same port), and I'm not sure what I'm doing differently here. Let me know if there is any further information I can provide which might clarify my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int ethwrite(char hostname[], int portno)
{
    int sockfd, n; // file descriptor, number of chars
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; // device address
    struct hostent *server; // pointer to host object
    char buffer[256];

    while(true)
    {
        // open socket
        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sockfd < 0) return -1; // couldn't open socket

        // parse host name
        server = gethostbyname(hostname);
        if (server == NULL) return -2;// host not found

        // zero the server address array and parse
        bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);

        // connect to server
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
        if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
            return -3; // couldn't connect

        printf("Input: ");
        bzero(buffer,256);
        fgets(buffer,255,stdin); // take user input and write to buffer

        // write command to socket
        n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
        if (n < 0) return -4; // couldn't write to socket

        // zero the buffer and read from the socket
        bzero(buffer,256);
        n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
        if (n < 0) return -5; // couldn't read socket

        printf("Output: %s\n",buffer);

        close(sockfd); // close socket
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int status = ethwrite((char *)"10.13.70.230", 23);
    printf("Returned status: %i\n",status);
    return status;
}
```

Comment: telnet sends the network newline "CR LF" while fgets will read the local newline into the buffer, which would be just "LF" on Linux, for example.  Try adding the CR and increasing the length by 1.

Comment: Also, `read()` returns the number of bytes actually read, and does not null-terminate `buffer`. So, either add a null terminator yourself, or simply pass `n` to `printf()`, so it doesn't go outside the bounds of `buffer`.

Comment: tried appending a CR but no luck. I recieved the same output for the first command and somehow the second command attempt ended the program without response. I will definitely add the n to printf() as suggested, but this does not solve the problem either.

Comment: I just noticed the same pattern of recieving the ">" character output every other time persists even if I just press enter repeatedly, which might mean the device is ONLY recieving the CR somehow, despite the write command returning the correct number of chars written. Any ideas?

Comment: I have confirmed the device is recieving the command properly, so that means my problem is with the read operation. Does this give anyone any ideas?